# how do I automatically login to PC desktop with python or window task scheduler?

Tags: python, windows

I have scheduled python script to run everyday. However the code uses pyautogui which requires the PC to be fully awaken and logged in.

So how do I log into my PC automatically everyday?

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible to "login" to a windows system from a scheduler task. It can execute under a specific account, and it can interact with the desktop if the accounts match, but I do not know whether it is enough for pyautogui. I know that previous versions of Windows allowed *auto login" meaning that if the account had no password, the machine did an automatic login, unsure for Windows 10 or 11. Maybe you could find that info on SuperUser...

Comment: What's the sense of GUI in a scheduled task? A GUI is interactive by definition and hence can't be scheduled :-)